# powershell modify windows registry entry

Tags: powershell, registry

Scenario is as follows:

A certain installer script (powershell) must call a setup.exe who creates a windows registry entry.

Afterwards, the custom installer shall modify that registry entry.

The most relevant snippet is:

```
$TNS_NAMES_Key                  = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\ODP.NET.Managed\4.122.19.1"
$TNS_NAMES_Value                = "C:\XXX\XXX\c.19.0.0.0.0_64\product\19.0.0\client_1\network\admin\NonExistentDirectory"
Write-Host (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss") "BEFORE:"
$foo                            = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $TNS_NAMES_Key -Name "TNS_ADMIN"
Write-Host $foo

Try 
{
    Set-Itemproperty -Path $($TNS_NAMES_Key) -Name 'TNS_ADMIN' -Value $($TNS_NAMES_Value) -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException]
{
    Write-Host (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss") "WARNING al cambiar la variable de registro $($TNS_NAMES_Key) : $($_.Exception.Message)"
    $errors_setting_registry_key = $true
}
catch
{
    Write-Host (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss") "CATCH GLOBAL: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    $errors_setting_registry_key = $true
}

#...
Write-Host (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss") "AFTER:"
$foo        = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $TNS_NAMES_Key -Name "TNS_ADMIN"
Write-Host $foo
```

This produces a logfile (by means of `Start-Transcript`) such as

```
2023-04-10_08:21:07 BEFORE:
C:\XXX\XXX\c.19.0.0.0.0_64\product\19.0.0\client_1\network\admin
2023-04-10_08:21:07 AFTER:
C:\XXX\XXX\c.19.0.0.0.0_64\product\19.0.0\client_1\network\admin\NonExistentDirectory
```

Yet, after the script is finished, the windows registry key has the "BEFORE" value.

Just like if a `commit` was missing.

Is the code wrong in any aspect?

Comment: In case it is relevant, the powershell script is run with enough privileges, by means of SCCM, a Microsoft massive-software-distribution system, whose client runs in a 32-bit environment (or so I have been told)

Comment: Are you checking the 64-bit or 32-bit view of the registry afterwards?

Comment: Sorry, I keep two versions (x86. x64) and I mixed up the log output of one and the snippet of the other. I just edited the question